# Creating Centrelines from Road Polygons using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon

I want to create center lines from road polygons.

Are there any automated tools in QGIS to do this?

I am including a Screenshot of my vector file below.

[image]

Comment: What you are looking for is call skeletisation, a search on that should get you some idea

Comment: Just rephrasing; a keyword `skeleton` may add more options...I would suggest to look at `v.voronoi.skeleton` among others.